# Get message and title From Push Notification GCM to activity

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have try to get a `message` and `title` from gcm push notification to the activity but it's not work. Here my code below:

**sendNotification in GcmIntentService.java Class**:

```
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("message", msg);

        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP| Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        Log.e("message", msg);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent , 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg);


        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
```

**NotificationActivity.java Class**

```
Toast.makeText(this, "message"+ getIntent().getStringExtra("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Thank You!

Comment: put your activity code here

Comment: public class NotificationActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_notification);


        Toast.makeText(this, "message"+ getIntent().getStringExtra("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

Comment: post you json in the question

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
//onCreate() or onNewIntent() method
bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null && bundle.getString("message") != null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "message"+ getIntent().getExtra().getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

add above condition

Comment: I tried this but it show like this java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: put your json...put your GCMintentservice full code...do you get proper msg in push notification?

Comment: please check my updated answer so your app is not crash
i think you can not getting value in msg in sendNotification() method.so please provide full code.